# Finite dimensional central division $\mathbb K$-algebra as a subalgebra of a matrix $\mathbb K$-algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, noncommutative-algebra, splitting-field, division-algebras

The question is as follows:

> > A finite-dimensional central division $\mathbb K$-algebra $D$  is a $\mathbb K$-algebra isomorphic to a subalgebra  of $M_r(\mathbb K)$ if and only if $\dim_{\mathbb K} D \mid r$.

In what comes, we already know that the other direction is true by a beautiful answer from @Algeboy.

Also, I understood that the comment by @Jyrki give a very nice and reasonable way for to show the statement. But I don't know how to use it.

For to prove this statement, I think for to show the statement, I think we need to use the notion of splitting field for the central division algebra $D$
of dimension say $d^2$ and to show that $[L:K]=rd$ by using $[D:K]=[L:K]^2$. I know how to prove these facts but I still do not know how to apply it for to prove our statement?

Also there is some hint for to prove it in the book [Finite dimensional division algebras over fields (1996 Springer)](http://www.springer.com/la/book/9783540570295) by Nathan Jacobson and [you can download it by clicking on this link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iGUWky4VAYBFL8zHZ0Dbky7EPIFoExPN/view?), in the beginning of the section 2.12 is written that this is a direct sequence from the theorem 2.3.17 and some statements from its proof. But I still cannot see it!

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you use the fact that $D$ acts faithfully on itself by $\Bbb{K}$-linear transformation? So if $\dim_{\Bbb{K}}D=r$ this action can be viewed as embedding $D$ into $M_r(\Bbb{K})$. Use action on $D^\ell$ iff $\dim_{\Bbb{K}}D=r/\ell$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Many thanks for your comment! Can you please explain a bit more? Thanks!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Many thanks for your comment! But I think for to show the statement we need to use the notion of splitting field for the central division algebra $D$ of dimension say $d^2$ and to show that $[L:K]=rd$ by using $[D:K] =[L:K]^2$. I know how to prove these facts but I still do not know how to apply it for to prove the above mentioned statement? Can you please help me to prove it? Thanks!

Comment: The question is senseless as stated. I took time to understand that the claim is that $D$ is isomorphic as a $K$-algebra to a subalgebra of $M_r(K)$. To claim that something is a subring of something consists in proving that it's stable under ring operations...

Comment: Btw by editing you made Algeboy's answer obsolete... you were asking for an iff statement ad he proved the only nontrivial implication. If I understand correctly (trying to make sense of the question), the remaining implication is trivial.

Comment: @YCor Many thanks for your comment! Can you please let me know how to show that? I cannot see its triviality! I edited it again! Thanks!

Comment: @YCor Many thanks for your comment! Yes you are right! The question is how to see $D$ as a $\mathbb K$-algebra isomorphic to a subalgebra of $M_r(\mathbb K)$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write $d=\dim_K(D)$. Consider the set $D^m$ for a natural number $m$.
Then $D^m$ is a right $D$-module, and has dimension $md$ as a vector
space over $D$. Choose a basis $B$ for $D^m$ over $K$. Each right multiplication map $\rho_a:x\to xa$ on $D^m$ is a $K$-vector endomorphism
of $D^m$. Expressing it in terms of the basis $B$ gives a matrix $N_a$.
Then $a\to N_a$ is a homomorphism from $D$ to $M_{md}(K)$. As $D$
is simple, its image is isomorphic to $D$ and is a subring of $M_{md}(K)$.

Conversely consider an embedding $\phi:D\to M_n(K)$. Then $K^n$
becomes a right $D$-module via $v\cdot a=v\phi(a)$. For a division
ring, module theory follows the same lines as vector space theory
over a field: every module is free. Thus $K^n\cong D^m$ as a $D$-module
for some $m$. Then $n=md$ on counting dimensions over $K$.

Comment: Uh very nice and knowledgeable answer! Thank you very much! I understood whole part of it! Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If $D$ is a unital subring of $M_r(K)$ then $K^r$ is a unital $D$-module.  But $D$ is a division ring so this means $K^r$ is a $D$-vector spaces, i.e. $K^r=D^m$ for $m=\dim_D K^r$.  Evidently $r=m\dim D$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! But sorry I cannot understand some part of it. Why $K^r$ is an unital $D$-module? and why $K^r$ becomes a $D$-vector space? And how to show the sufficiency part, please? Thanks!

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! Can you please explain it a bit more? And also can you please let me know how to do the other part? Thanks!

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! I think for to show the statement we need to use the notion of splitting field for the central division algebra $D$ of dimension say $d^2$ and to show that $[L:K]=rd$ by using $[D:K] =[L:K]^2$. I know how to prove these facts but I still do not know how to apply it for to prove the above mentioned statement? Can you please help me to prove it? Thanks!

Comment: Can you please also let me know how to show the other part? Thanks!